Is there a type to represent any JSON serializable object in Python?
It is my understanding that json.load returns any.
I do not believe I can change the built-in typing, but I think it would be better to use more specific typing in my programs, since not all objects are JSON serializable. However, such list would be long and repetitive.
Are there any recommendations?

My following suggestion isn't all-encompassing, but I guess it's one way you could retype JSON that is a little bit more descriptive without being long and redundant. from typing import Iterable then Json = dict | Iterable. Then use Json as a typehint.

Specifying the type doesn't really help much. If you want to validate that data you load from (e.g.) JSON matches what you expect, use e.g. https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/

For one, I would use a schema in order to validate everything I receive. Or, perhaps, use a framework that does JSON-based serialization and gives you proper data objects.

json.load() takes hook functions that can return custom types, so it can return types that don't have a standard JSON seralization.

Duplicates: Define a jsonable type using mypy / PEP-526, Type-Hinting JSON Object Rigorously, Type hinting a JSON object in Python, How do I type annotate JSON data in Python?.

If I understand correctly the issue is that json.loads returns a typing Any. Since that is ambigious you want a more robust solution to this. There are ways to define your own TypeVars. Maybe this is what you are looking for.
from typing import Generic, TypeVar
import json

SerializableField = TypeVar('SerializableField', str, int, float, bool)
Serializable = TypeVar('Serializable',
                       dict[str, SerializableField],
                       list[SerializableField],
                       tuple[SerializableField],
                       set[SerializableField],
                       SerializableField)


class JSONStack(Generic[Serializable]):
    def __init__(self, values: Serializable) -> None:
        self.values = values

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"JSONStack({self.values})"


values: Serializable = json.loads('{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}')

print(JSONStack(values))

however, use this kind of solution with caution. This can be useful if you have known or limited use case but i do not recommend this for generic applications as JSON can be quite complex. There is a reason json.loads return Any and not a specific datatype.
Lastly if you have a simple use case then using Generic and TypeVar is huge overhead anyway.
